# Adding a sharepoint webpage without storing it in a document library?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to do something very simple: Add a "Basic page" to a sharepoint site, and have it appear in the quick launch side navigation. But it insists on storing it in a document library. Is there anyway to not store it in a document library?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the page to the site as a [module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453137.aspx).

The following XML is how you can register the module for use with SharePoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements
  Id="<GUID />"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="<Name />" >
    <File Path="<Feature Sub-Directory />"
          Url="<URL on SharePoint site />"
    />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

To get the navigation working use a feature receiver.  This is a good place to start for modifying the navigation programmatically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558975.aspx